# Determine Files from git which are deleted from local machine

Tags: git, github

I have commited some file into git but accidentally remove from local machine. I have not push those changes to https://github.com/goswamia/DataStructureInPythonC.git as I have to update code. I have followed multiple link but not able to get files from  git which are commited into git.

> On branch master
>
> Initial commit
>
> Untracked files:   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be
>   committed)
>
> graph/
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to
>   track)

Comment: Your question is self-contradictory. When you commit into git, it doesn't save the commit on a remote server - that's what push does. So if you have literally deleted the data, including the local git repository, from the local machine, it's gone, there's no getting it back. However, if you still have the local git repository, you can check out the old commits as shown in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have commited changes and deleted a branch or if you used a hard reset you can reset your commit with your **reflog**.

```
git reflog <<< find your commit
```

Then you can use the reflog id and checkout that state.

```
git checkout reflogid
```

http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits

Here is a good tutorial.